# How to configure multiple table rate and multiple type shipping?

Tags: shipping

I am using magento 1.7. I am failing to configure multiple table rates with multiple types of shipping and I don't want to buy any extensions.

```
  Mainland UK   Estimated Delivery  Postage & Packing
 Free Delivery 
    Orders over £50
    2-5 days    FREE
 Orders Under £50
    2-5 days    £2.95
 Two Day Delivery
    48 hrs if ordered before 1pm    £3.95
 Express Next Day 1pm
    if ordered before 1pm   £6.95
 Saturday Delivery
    next available Saturday £12.95

  International
Western Europe Postage & Packing £7.95
Rest of Europe 'Tax Free' Postage & Packing £9.95
USA & Canada 'Tax Free' Postage & Packing £14.00
Middle East & Africa 'Tax Free' 5- 10 days from dispatch Postage & Packing £14.00
Far East & Australasia 'Tax Free' Postage & Packing £14.00
```

Here are my shipping criteria if you have any suggestion or any free extension that will be helpfull to configure this shipping price.

Comment: I have tried to make this extension work too, but I don't get any rates returned on front end. At webshopapps troubleshooting page the issue is due to incorrect serial key. As it is supposed to be free, there is no serial key to insert, neither is there a field to insert it in.
If anyone could make this plugin work, please let me know. So I don't need to wonder if this is just a cheap trick to make us buy the more advanced version. For me I don't need the more advanced functions, I only need an extra table rate.
I can not help thinking that there's a reason for removing it from Magento-connect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to buy an extension. You should be able to use the Free Matrix Rate Plugin by webshopapps.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension-certified-bug-free.html

Unless you need to start refining by postcodes this should more the fit the requirements.

Comment: i have tried but its generate fatel error

Comment: What's the error you're receiving? Did you install it via magento connect? Make sure all your permissions are correct and you clear the var/cache/ directory

Comment: yes i have clear cache but i am unable to install via magento connect just install it manually now showing any error just a blank page i also enable error reporting

Comment: Make sure your error reporting is set to set to E_ALL. Also you may need to logout and back into the admin after installing an extension. Blank pages can sometimes be a memory issue are you working on a local dev environment? Make sure your execution time and memory limits are sufficient in your php.ini

Comment: You can download it direct from the webshopapps site. There are no issues with the extn, contact us for support if required.

Comment: @JohnNzime Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps matrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate.

Comment: Anyone knows how to give free shipping using Webshopapps  Matrix Rates in SHopping Cart Pricing rule?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help you: https://github.com/thebod/Thebod_Shippingrates

The code ist 100% free, so, if you want, feel free to add custom filters. Might be easier than the Matrixrate extension.

If you need any support let me know!